# Replace http call with empty Promise

Tags: typescript

I'd like to transform the following function so that it no longer makes an http call. Instead the function should return the same result as when there is a 404 error:

```
private getMessages(fileName: string, name: string, 
        id: number): Promise<Message[]> {

        let result = this.http
            .get(`${FILE_BASE_URL}/${fileName}`)
            .toPromise()
            .then(response => response.json().array as Message[])
            .catch(response => {
                if (response.status === 404) {
                    console.error(" response.status === 404 ");
                    return []
                } else {
                    throw response
                }
            })

        return result;
    }
```

I'm learning about Promise in typescript. Could someone help please ?

Comment: `private getMessages(fileName: string, name: string, 
        id: number): Promise<Message[]> { return Promise.resolve([])
    }`, perhaps?

Comment: That looks like Angular code. You're using the old, deprecated Http service instead of the new, documented HttpClient class. You're also using promises instead of simply use observables. And you're using an old version of RxJS, too. If you're learning, lern the current stuff, not the old one. Your method should return an observable, and you should simply return `of([])`.

Comment: You can tell http you'll give it a call later in the week...

Comment: Thanks for the help :) @JLRishe please post your comment as the answer and I'll accept it. Best regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that the 404 case results in a promise for an empty array, so to obtain the same result, you can just return a promise for an empty array:

```
private getMessages(fileName: string, name: string, id: number): Promise<Message[]> {
    return Promise.resolve([]);
}
```